How can I add custom classes per column/item in a responsive grid view?
It looks like all other display formats in the settings allows you to set a class for columns and rows, however in the settings for Responsive Grid there is no option.  You can set these in the standard Grids setting, so I'm perplexed why this isn't an option for Responsive Grid.
I want to style different grids separately, but the only class output is views-view-responsive-grid__item, so it's all or nothing unless I'm missing something.
